# How do I get validation for a form being rendered by the route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have two forms, in which the first one I create the country and the other one I create the city (however this one to create the city I need the country created and chosen).

So what happens is this:

1. I have a route to the country creation form
2. I have a route for creating cities, which also renders the same form
   as (1).

However, I need the validation of the first form, in order to disable the city creation button.

**How do I do this using good practices?**

**ROUTES**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        component: MasterPageComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'search', component: SearchPageComponent },
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: CreatePageComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: 'country', pathMatch: 'full', component: CreateCountryPageComponent },
                    { path: 'city', pathMatch: 'full', component: CreateCityPageComponent, children: [{ path: '', component: CreateCountryFormComponent }] },
                ],
            },
            { path: '**', component: NotFoundPageComponent },
        ],
    },
];
```

**FORM CITY COMPONENT:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'zx-create-city-form',
    template: `
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        <zx-create-generic-form
            [fmGroup]="cityForm"
            [fmControlName]="'cities'"
            [optionList]="cityList"
            [titleText]="'Selecione uma das Cidades:'"
            [errorText]=""
            [successText]=""
        ></zx-create-generic-form>
    `,
})
export class CreateCityFormComponent implements OnInit {
    cityForm!: FormGroup;
    cityList: any[] = [
        { text: 'Arizona2', value: 'AZ' },
        { text: 'California3', value: 'CA' },
        { text: 'Colorado4', value: 'CO' },
        { text: 'New York5', value: 'NY' },
        { text: 'Pennsylvania6', value: 'PA' },
    ];

    constructor(protected readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.cityForm = formBuilder.group({
            cities: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could go in a comment but I don't have enough rep lol.

I am not sure if its the best practice but I would create a service to connect the two.

onCountrySelect I would emit an event through the service that a country has been selected.

your city form would be subscribed to changes on that service observable. and now you can disable your city creation.